# GPU AMD RX 5500 GT ubuntu 20.04 ocacionally not recognized

Tags: drivers, 20.04, graphics, gpu

I have installed the drivers for my AMD GPU in Ubuntu 20.04. But when I reboot the system sometimes it does not recognized the GPU. When I go to Settings>>About I don't see the right name of the card.
On top, when I run the command: lshw -C video I don't see any driver under the configuration line (although I installed it before).

Why might be this is happening?

thanks